# Shell prompt in tmux session is much slower and sluggish

Tags: command-line, tmux

Why is it that in shell prompt in a `tmux` session, it is significantly slower and sluggish than plainly in terminal with `bash`? Even for just having a new line of prompt, i.e. hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute current command line?

Comment: I'm not experiencing that issue myself, so I have no clue.

Comment: I don't think I'm having this issue but I will say that it does usually take longer to initially load `screen` or `tmux` compared to simply loading bash but that's because it has to initially load both `screen` or `tmux` and then load `bash`.

Comment: [This thread](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/3352#issuecomment-1280147570) seems to explain some of it and it may have to do with your scrollback limit or lack thereof.

Comment: [More discussion here](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/5ovfgz/tmux_really_slows_down_the_terminal_performance_a/). It looks like `tmux` is slower than `screen` although `screen` might take some getting used to.

Answer (score 0):

There are several documented cases ([here](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/5ovfgz/tmux_really_slows_down_the_terminal_performance_a/) and [here](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/3352)) where `tmux` is evidently slower than a raw terminal.

##### 1. When printing a large amount of output

It seems `tmux` uses more time to print a very large number of characters to the screen. [This test was done](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/5ovfgz/tmux_really_slows_down_the_terminal_performance_a/) to show this (with comparison to GNU screen:

```
  $ time cat /usr/share/dict/words
  real  0m0.159s
  user  0m0.002s
  sys   0m0.154s

  $ tmux
  $ time cat /usr/share/dict/words
  real    0m2.044s
  user    0m0.000s
  sys     0m0.253s

  $ screen
  $ time cat /usr/share/dict/words
  real    0m0.808s
  user    0m0.001s
  sys     0m0.252s
```

##### 2. When the scrollback buffer is too large

It's also evident that if your `history-limit` option is set too high, it will cause a slowdown in `tmux`. The default `history-limit` in `tmux` is 2000 lines. It should be safe to set this considerably higher, but if you exceed 1 million lines, [it appears to have a noticeable effect](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/3352).

The history limit can be set with this option in `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -g history-limit 10000
```